Llm-client in spacemacs
Following these instructions, I tried to install llm-client layer to my spacemacs.
Spacemacs tells me "Unknown layer llm-client declared in dot file".
Have you any idea what to do ?

You have to be on the develop branch. If you have specified gptel (llm-client :variables llm-client-enable-gptel t) the major mode can be enabled using the gptel command.
